# Add "Not about Apple products" to close vote reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, voting

I've seen a default "Not about Apple products and not in scope of this site etc." as closing reason.
It does not show up in my options, is it diamond mod only?

Can this be added to the 3k rep closing vote?

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: I presume you're referring to 'This question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center.'?

Comment: the wording is not good as any app running on  Apple hardware is on topic whilst this text says it is not. However a better way of saying this should be a closing message

Comment: @Mark The close reason in the question appears to be a paraphrasing.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside -no the text he quoted I have seen recently - however your text is better

Comment: @Mark [This question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134656/excel-formula-for-multiplying-columns) Rob used the free-form close reason box with a custom written close reason, then someone else agreed with this reason in the close box. That reason is not an official reason.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Yes although your better text is not standard either and I think this meta question should ask for that (and the actual question I suspect is on topic he just forgot to add which spreadsheet )

Comment: @Mark My text is standard: it's the off-topic text used when no other reason is used.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Ah However when I tried to close it does not show up as a reason in the 3k close reasons - I think it should be shown there - then we would not get Rob (and others) trying to make up a similar close reason

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

After 3k, blatantly off-topic gets replaced with "Other" and one should explain how it is off-topic.

I suggest you use magic links in the close reason so that after commenting, they lead to the right page. For e.g.:

> ... because this is off-topic as per [help/on-topic]

[Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments)